# Actionscript error #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm just a beginner at this and I would really appreciate some help.
This is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var currentButton:MovieClip
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
button4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    currentButton.alpha = 1;
    currentButton.mouseEnabled = true;
    currentButton = event.target as MovieClip;
    trace("CLICK");
    currentButton.alpha = 0.7;
    currentButton.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

But I get this error when I click on a button:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>           at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/mouseClick()

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code has some problem with your `currentButton` object.

I wonder adding following line at the beginning of your mouseClick function should solve your problem:

```
function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var currentButton:MovieClip = event.currentTarget; // Giving proper type to an object is better practise, but since your button objects appear unknown, I have assumed them as MovieClip
    currentButton.alpha = 1;
...
```